# How to make an xml layout from a custom view in Android?

Tags: android, view

In my application, I have two custom views for both `landscape` and `portrait` mode and I am using fragments to switch between these views but I am not able to do that since my these views are custom views `(CustomView extends View)` and not inflated from `xml` layout files. So that is my problem : I would like to know the way to convert these views to `xml` files and so be able to inflate from them as normal `xml layouts`.

Thanks

My Custom view :

```
public class control extends View{

    private Paint paint;

    public control(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(12);
        paint.setColor(0xFF668800);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText("TEEEST", 100, 100, paint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        this.setMeasuredDimension(150,200);     
    }
}
```

PM_Fragment class

```
public class PM_Fragment extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
        * Inflate the layout for this fragment
        */
        return inflater.inflate(
        /*This method returns a view wich be the content view of the Activity : in this case it inflates 
        a layout from R.layout.pm_fragment (xml layout) but i like it to  return my custom view 
        (control) instead of that xml layout. that is exactly my question 
        */
        R.layout.pm_fragment, container, false);
   }
}
```

Comment: Share your implemented code.

Comment: `convert views to xml files` - this makes no sense.  Do you mean inflate your custom view from a layout XML file?  Adding a custom view to a layout XML is no different to adding any other view.  You just need to add the namespace.

Comment: I mean making a new xml layout file wich will represent my custom view